# Call a function within a message box, timer

Tags: powershell, timer, messagebox

I have a timer that I setting up for one of my scripts, I have all of the pieces setup but cannot seem to get the timer to call within the box, it will call in powershell and then bring up the box. What I am looking to do is have it countdown for 2 minutes then close. Below is my code

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName ("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$x = 2*60
$length = $x / 100

Function timer () 
{While($x -gt 0) {
$min = [int](([string]($x/60)).split('.')[0])
$text = " " + $min + " minutes " + ($x % 60) + " seconds left"
Write-Progress "Building Account" -status $text -perc ($x/$length)
start-sleep -s 1
$x--
}
}


$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Timer Example"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(330,380) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$lblLog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblLog.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,230) 
$lblLog.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20) 
$lblLog.Text = timer

$objForm.Controls.Add($lblLog) 

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})

[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code creates the Label object then loops through the entirety of the countdown before even adding it to the form. PowerShell is single-thread, meaning you can EITHER have code running, or a responsive form. If you want both, it gets very complicated very quickly.

Jobs aren't really good practice and I've never used them with a form myself, ideally you would be using another runspace.

```
$x = 100

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Timer Example"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(330,380) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$lblLog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblLog.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,230) 
$lblLog.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$lblLog.Text = "Testing"
$objForm.Controls.Add($lblLog)

[PowerShell]$command = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
    Param
    (
        [System.Windows.Forms.Label]$label,
        $x
    )
    While($x -gt 0) {
        $min = [int](([string]($x/60)).split('.')[0])
        $text = " " + $min + " minutes " + ($x % 60) + " seconds left"
        $label.BeginInvoke([System.Action[string]]{
            Param($text)

            $label.Text = $text
        }, $text)
        start-sleep -s 1
        $x--
    }
})
$command.AddParameters(@($lblLog, $x)) | Out-Null

$command.BeginInvoke() | Out-Null
$objForm.ShowDialog()
```

What this does is create another runspace where PowerShell can run in parallel to the main console, and put the timer in there. Forms however are single thread too, so we need to invoke the action of updating the Label (kind of like saying "Hey, can you do this when you're free?"). We use `BeginInvoke` which just tells it to update but doesn't wait, because you're running a timer and having to wait for the form to be available will throw off your counter.

This tests OK for me but the form and label will need resizing to suit your purposes.

Comment: Oh, just a note, most streams (such as Output and Error) aren't redirected to the main console from separate runspaces (though for some reason Warning is??) - I don't know about Progress but I didn't get anything on my test.

Comment: $length isn't passed anyway so might be worth editing it out (it does actually go into the Streams property). Lastly this does throw a few errors (also into Streams) because $command starts running before the form is shown, meaning it tries to update the label once or twice before it's available. You could put in a two second wait or use a try/catch or even just ignore it, still runs okay.